# Two strings appear to be equal, but they are not

Tags: java, string, split

I want to open a file using the argument I get via a socket. When I extract the filename using `split()`, the file does not open. But when I hardcode the value, it does open.

What am I missing here? I would expect the strings to be equal.

```
String name = str.split(";")[2];

System.out.println("Filename: " + name);

String path1 = new String("Input_Blatt3/Sample.txt");
String path2 = new String("Input_Blatt3/" + name);

System.out.println("Path1: " + path1);
System.out.println("Path2: " + path2);

System.out.println("path1.equals(path2) = " + path1.equals(path2));
```

Output:

```
Path1: Input_Blatt3/Sample.txt
Path2: Input_Blatt3/Sample.txt
path1.equals(path2) = false
```

Comment: Try: `System.out.printf("Filename: ^%s^%n", name);` and see what appears between the `^` characters.

Comment: Show us what is the value of `str`.

Comment: you can also compare the characters of each string...unicode has a lot of characters that look the same but are not (additionally to white spaces or other characters that do not get printed, as already answered)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There could be some trailing white spaces, which you would not see at the console output.

You can try `name.strip()` (or `trim()` if your JDK version is lower 11) to ensure that there's nothing but the file name in the string.

Also, you can find the index of the first mismatching character of these two strings using [`Arrays.mismatch()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Arrays.html#mismatch(char%5B%5D,char%5B%5D)):

```
int indexOfMismatch = Arrays.mismatch(str1.toCharArray(), str2.toCharArray());
```

In case if the strings are equal, `indexOfMismatch` would be `-1`.

Comment: Thanks, I am using strip() on the path string but it doesn't resolve the issue
ath: [B@2a84aee7
Path2: [B@a09ee92
Path equals Path2: false

Comment: @nubels But the string you've listed `[B@2a84aee7` and `[B@a09ee92` are not the same. `false` should be the expected outcome.

Comment: Yes, but I want to open the file that has been specified via the socket and not the hardcoded one.

Comment: @nubels Are these file-names are consist of ASCII -characters only? You can try the following check `int indexOfMismatch = Arrays.mismatch(str1.toCharArray(), str2.toCharArray());` to find the first character in these strings that doesn't match (if they are equal, the result should be `-1`).

Answer (score 2):

There could be unprintable characters hidden in the String.
Use `getBytes` to get all the characters of a String and print those. You'll probably find something you didn't expect.

You need to iterate over the byte array to print each byte individually, as in the following method:

```java
private static void printBytes(String string) {
    System.out.println("printing " + string);
    for (byte aByte : string.getBytes()) {
        System.out.println( aByte );
    }
}
```

Alternatively you could also `replace` everything that isn't a printable character with nothing.

Comment: A different comment shows OP is getting `[B@`, so evidently, it needs to be said: To print the thing you get from `.getBytes()`: `System.out.println(Arrays.toString(str.getBytes())`.

Comment: @rzwitserloot I updated my answer to make that a little clearer. I went for a more verbose explicit loop, hoping to make this easier to understand